# iOS app does not ask camera and microphone permissions on TestFlight?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, mobile

I've an issue that is unusual. When I test my app with XCode evertything is working on my iphone and the other iphones, the app asks to user for all permissions. But when I added my app to TestFlight, the app does not ask camera and microphone permissions to user? "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" and "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" keys are already added to info.plist file. The app behaves different on TestFlight, how can it be?

Comment: Have you already run your app on that device (Even a development build) and already answered the questions?  What permissions are shown in the settings for your app?  What happens when your app tries to access the camera or microphone?

Comment: I delete the app and reinstall it for each TestFlight build. On TestFlight build Location, Siri & Search, Notifications and Background App Refresh shown in app settings, on xcode debug there are also camera and microphone permissions in addition to another permissions.

Comment: Maybe it's just remembers user's choice?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I delete the app and reinstall it for each TestFlight build and I always click Yes to permission requests. On TestFlight builds, it does not show any permission request and does not open camera.

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure your app has permission before capturing media, follow the steps below.

**Configure Your App's Info.plist File**

iOS requires that your app provide static messages to display to the user when the system asks for camera or microphone permission:

- If your app uses device cameras, include the Privacy - Camera Usage
  Description key in your app’s Info.plist file.
- If your app uses device photo library, include the Privacy - Photo
  Library Usage Description key in your app’s Info.plist file

**Verify and Request Authorization for Capture**

You can add below code in AppDelegate main file OR while click on capture media to request access authorization.

```
import AVFoundation

AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in

            if granted {
            // Setup your code.
            }
        }
```

**Apple Ref Link** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios

Comment: Is this requirement normally waived when working in simulator? I am able to access without adding permissions. Or something else can be at play?

Answer (score 0):

If the user has previously denied the use of the camera, then the status will be AVAuthorizationStatusDenied and the dialog will not be displayed when asking for permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we faced with the similar issue recently. In our case, the solution was related to signing.

If you're checked the automatically manage signing box in Xcode, you can try this to fix this issue:

1. Create 'Distribution' certificate on Apple Developer Console.
2. Create 'App Store' provisioning profile by selecting the created certificate in Step 1.
3. Download certificate and add to your keychain.
4. In Xcode update the release signing part with this newly created provisioning profile and certificate.

By these steps we fixed our permission issue in TestFlight. I hope this post will help someone in someday.

Comment: Very useful information, thank you very much.